# What are the differences between a VESC and a E-bike controller?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm trying to figure out how do a VESC and a generic e-Bike controller differ?

Besides the custom controls and the higher rating of the VESC are there any other differences?

Parts:

[The Vesc:](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000438827676.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.52762c9fm4pXei&algo_pvid=44da5fe6-748b-4f78-9696-eb61576ef61e&algo_expid=44da5fe6-748b-4f78-9696-eb61576ef61e-0&btsid=0b0a119a16197063918597517e7fc0&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

- 3-12s battery
- 50A continuous
- 150a max
- £56

[The E-Bike Controller:](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32912585673.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.7cf21645fGUWuR&algo_pvid=6ae103a1-4976-4a48-8d5e-5616cbfaf8d9&algo_expid=6ae103a1-4976-4a48-8d5e-5616cbfaf8d9-5&btsid=2100bdde16197064323066239eb20f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

- 10-12s battery
- 22A continuous
- 35A max
- £17

[The hub motors:](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/353438154193?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3D8c43fc83d6df401c843d0a2f1e75ca31%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D15%26mehot%3Dnone%26sd%3D353438154193%26itm%3D353438154193%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3A7964c0f4-a8f2-11eb-9172-625578c0056d%7Cparentrq%3A1de936631790a1b7e42087eafff252dc%7Ciid%3A1)

- 75kv
- 90mm diameter
- 36v
- 600w max power
- £130

I want to get these two hub motors and 2 e-bike controllers and use them on my longboard.

My plan is to use the folowings:

1. 2 e-bike controllers
2. 2 90mm hub motors
3. 10s2p using ncr21700
4. A custom remote out of a WII nunchuk using arduino and NRF24

I feel like im missing something regarding the controllers and I dont want to buy them before some confirmation cuz the postage take 1 to 2 months.

Comment: One's "based on" open-source, the other isn't.

Comment: Hardware for VESC referenced is based on open-source hardware.  Software is open sourced.  VESC was designed for your application.  Easier to add your custom remote with open source hardware/software.

Answer (score 3):

The E-bike controller appears to have a PWM AC output for closed-loop control of a brushless permanent magnet motor.

The VESC looks like it may have a similar capability.

Looking at just the online sales information, it is difficult to evaluate what is being offered with either product.

The E-bike controller is the type that is suitable for the linked motors, but you should carefully study the complete documentation for both the selected controllers and motors. If you can not obtain and study the documentation before purchasing, look elsewhere. If you can not verify suitability, look elsewhere.

Coordinating two motors that drive the same vehicle will be challenging.

Comment: VESC is for BLDC, not brushed motor.

Comment: Yes, I see now there is more to the VESC than was first apparent. I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Besides the custom controls and the higher rating of the VESC are
> there any other differences?

Isn't that enough? Considering the sheer amount of capabilities hidden behind "custom controls" and more than 12 times current available (some VESC controllers go up to 300A continuous).

VESC provides multitude of control protocols, like CAN, USB, UAVCAN and UART. Some come with BLE wireless controllers, some have built-in IMU chips. All allow advanced configuration via Android an PC applications.

The e-bike controllers (at least the ones I have experience with) are very primitive devices. It is like comparing apples to oranges, really.

On the down side, however, is that being quite new open source project developed pretty much by one person, VESC is not a mature product. I believe it will be great when all the bugs flushed out and software "polished", and we are considering using these in commercial products some day.